# Power shell Script to Enable Server level and databases triggers

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell, triggers, database-trigger

What is the best way to enable all server level and DB level triggers for multiple server?
Thanks

Comment: Sorry the code formatter missed the code, any ideas on how to publish the code properly?

Comment: i will change this post, thank you

Comment: @Larnu i dont have enough reputation, can i still be able to answer my question? Thx

Comment: nice script! checkout the dbatools project (https://dbatools.io/commands/) and the trigger related commands for some inspiration.

Comment: will delete it. sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Using Powershell SQLSERVER module:

-- Run below command to install sqlserver power shell module

```
# install-module sqlserver
Import-Module sqlserver

# getting the servers list
$servers = Get-Content C:\sql\servers.txt

Foreach($server in $servers)
{

 cd sqlserver:/sql/$server

 # checking if a server has more than one instance
 IF ((dir).count -gt 1)
  {

 cd sqlserver:\sql\$server

 dir | %{ $instname = $_.displayname

            "***************************************$server $instname*************************************************"
            "Enabling Server Level Triggers on: $server\$instname"

            cd sqlserver:\sql\$server\$instname\triggers

            dir | %{$_.refresh()}

            # enabling server level triggers
            dir | ?{$_.isenabled -eq $false} | %{$_.isenabled = $true ; $_.alter() ; $_.refresh()}


            cd sqlserver:\sql\$server\$instname\databases

            # looping through the databases on each instance and enabling the triggers
            dir | %{ $DB = $_.name
                      cd sqlserver:\sql\$server\$instname\databases\$DB\Triggers

                      "Enabling Triggers on: $DB"
                      dir | %{$_.refresh()}
                      #$server

                      dir | ?{$_.isenabled -eq $false} | %{$_.isenabled = $true ; $_.alter() ; $_.refresh()}
                    }

         }
  }
  else # for servers with default instance 
  {
     cd sqlserver:\sql\$server\default

     cd sqlserver:\sql\$server\default\triggers
            "***************************************$server*************************************************"
            "Enabling Server Level Triggers on: $server\Default"

            dir | %{$_.refresh()}

            # enabling server level triggers
            dir | ?{$_.isenabled -eq $false} | %{$_.isenabled = $true ; $_.alter() ; $_.refresh()}


            cd sqlserver:\sql\$server\default\databases
            # looping through the databases on each instance and enabling the triggers
            dir | %{ $DB = $_.name
                      cd sqlserver:\sql\$server\default\databases\$DB\Triggers

                      "Enabling Triggers on: $DB"
                      dir | %{$_.refresh()}
                      #$server

                      dir | ?{$_.isenabled -eq $false} | %{$_.isenabled = $true ; $_.alter() ; $_.refresh()}
                    }


   }
}

Write-Host "Done....."

cd c:\

Start-Sleep -s 10
```